# Помогите разобраться с областями видимости (LEGB)

Tags: python

customer — словарь с данными клиента следующего вида: {"name": "Dima"} или {"name": "Boris", "discount": 0.15}
У вас есть глобальная переменная DEFAULT_DISCOUNT, которая определяет скидку для клиента, если у него нет поля discount.
price = price * (1 - discount)
Как мне из словаря взять значение discount?

```
DEFAULT_DISCOUNT = 0.05
    
    
    def get_discount_price_customer(price, customer):
```

Comment: `customer['discount']`

Comment: `customer.get('discount', DEFAULT_DISCOUNT)`, вернется второй аргумент, если значения по ключу не будет :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обратиться к значению словарю достаточно использовать `[]`:

```
customer = {"name": "Boris", "discount": 0.15}
print(customer['name']) # имя клиента
print(customer['discount']) # скидка клиента
```

В вашем случае, думаю нужно это:

```
DEFAULT_DISCOUNT = 0.05
customer = {"name": "Boris", "discount": 0.15}
def get_discount_price_customer(price, customer):
    return price*(1-customer.get('discount', DEFAULT_DISCOUNT))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)